# Adding new task dependencies to built-in SBT tasks?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to override or modify built-in SBT tasks (like compile) to depend on custom tasks in my own Build.scala? Overriding e.g. "compile" directly is not possible since it has been defined with lazy val and thus referring to super.compile emits a compiler error "super may be not be used on lazy value".

Comment: Possible duplicate for SBT 0.13 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8554992/1305344

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since this question appears when Googling how to add a dependency in SBT, and the current answers are [deprecated as of 0.13.x](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html) and removed in 1.0, here's the updated answer, assuming that `printAction` is the task that `compile` should depend on:

`(Compile / compile) := ((Compile / compile) dependsOn printAction).value`

Answer (score 17):

**Update: See arussell84's answer for a modern way to do this**

You should be able to do it like this:

in a .sbt file:

```
compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn jruby
```

Where jruby is a task key that you've defined in a project/something.scala file:

```
val jruby = TaskKey[Unit]("jruby", "run a jruby file")
```

Also, this isn't part of your question but you can just call regular Scala code:

```
compile <<= (compile in Compile) map { result =>
  println("in compile, something")
  result
}
```

Comment: There are so many 'compile's in there I can't work out how this generalizes to adding dependencies to other tasks. What to I do to add a dependency to 'stage'?

Comment: @ScottMorrison I think you say: `stage << stage dependsOn jruby`

Comment: This answer is outdated. See [the updated version I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654822/596329).

Answer (score 7):

Reply to self: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/ProjectDefinitionExamples#Insert_Task_Dependency tells the answer:

If you are using older 0.7.x SBT versions you can do this:

```
import sbt._
class SampleProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  lazy val printAction = task { print("Testing...") }
  override def compileAction = super.compileAction dependsOn(printAction)
}
```

Comment: Please note that this suggestion only works for 'older' SBT 0.7.x. The current 0.11 does it differently.

Comment: How does the new version do this?

Comment: This answer is outdated. See [the updated version I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654822/596329).

Answer (score -1):

In the `base_dir/project/` folder create a file `build.sbt` and put `libraryDependencies += ...` there.

That's the idiomatic SBT way to build your "build project", also known as "Meta Build".