# How to attach custom task to execute before the test task in sbt?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm using SBT with Play Framework.

I created a custom `TaskKey` to run JavaScript tests in my project:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Process._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val testJsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testJs", "Run javascript tests.") := {}

  val main = PlayProject("xxx", 1.0, Seq())
    .settings(defaultScalaSettings: _*)
    .settings(testJsTask)
}
```

So far so good.

I want to run this `testJsTask` always when someone executes the `test` task.

I guess it should be something as follows:

```
test in Test <<= (test in Test).dependsOn(testJsTask)
```

I've no idea how it should be defined exactly. How to add a dependency to an existing task like 'test' or 'build'?

**UPDATE**

After changes proposed by @Christian the build definition looks as follows:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val testJsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testJs", "Run tests for javascript client.")
  def testJs = {}

  val main = PlayProject("xxx", 1.0, Seq())
    .settings(defaultScalaSettings: _*)
    .settings(testJsTask := testJs)

  (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (testJs)
}
```

Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work either:

```
[error] /xxx/project/Build.scala:21: not found: value test
[error]   (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (testJs)
[error]    ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/xxx/project/}default-f468ae/compile:compile: Compilation failed
```

Comment: Have you been successful? Did my latest edit help you?

Comment: Unlucky I don't see way to do the same with Play version :/ I'll try to do few more tests and I'll report here if there will be any success.

Comment: I'm interested to see if you found a resolution.

Comment: just for future readers: `(test in Test) := (test in Test).dependsOn(otherTask).value` works for me

Answer (score 14):

This is one way to do it:

Define the task key:

```
val testJsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testJs", "Run javascript tests.")
```

Define the task in your projects settings:

```
testJsTask <<= testJs
```

Make test dependent on it:

```
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (testJs)
```

testJs can be defined as follows:

```
  def testJs = (streams) map { (s) => {
    s.log.info("Executing task testJs")
    // Your implementation
  }
```

[EDIT] You have to define the task dependencies within the projects settings. For
a "normal" project, you would do it the following way:

```
  lazy val testProject = Project(
    "testProject",
    file("testProject"),
    settings = defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      testJsTask <<= testJs,
      (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (testJsTask)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Somehow this looks wrong on incomplete to me. What I want to do is ensure, that when someone will run 'test' command, then except all other test it will execute also testJs. Also I see you didn't used ':= ' symbol at all, which I know is needed when building Tasks - or am I wrong?. EDIT: I see your edit, now it starts to make more sense, I'll try it right away ;)

Comment: You can directly define a task with :=. I prefer the other possibility, because then I can separate the task keys from the actual tasks.

Comment: I still have the same problem as before: Build.scala:19: not found: value test. [error]   (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (testJsTask)

Comment: Could you post your current build script?

Comment: I never used the play framework, but maybe a PlayProject does not have (test in Test)?

Comment: In PlayProject source code I don't see any changes for tests unlucky (btw. https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SettingsSBT). Also, I edited my first post.

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of SBT 1.1.0-RC1, the key line to make `test` dependent on `testJs` should be: `(Test / test) := ((Test / test) dependsOn testJs).value`

Answer (score 14):

Play 2.2.x uses SBT 0.13 (see [What’s new in Play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22)). That brings some new means of composing tasks in `build.sbt` itself (without resorting to a Scala file in `project/` subdirectory).

If you happen to use Play 2.2.x you could define the dependency between the tasks in `build.sbt` as follows:

```
lazy val testJsTask = taskKey[Unit]("Run JavaScript tests.")

testJsTask := {
  println("Running JavaScript tests...")
  java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)
  println("...done.")
}

test in Test := {
  testJsTask.value
  (test in Test).value
}
```

See [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks) in the official documentation of SBT for more details.

Comment: Does this run the tasks sequentially or in concurrently?

Comment: Sequentially. First testJsTask, then test task.

Comment: As far is I understand this is not correct @htomek  http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks
Use `Def.sequential()` to run tasks in order http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Sequencing.html

Answer (score 0):

For me using `dependsOn` syntax didn't work. Instead I used tests' [setup functionality](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Setup+and+Cleanup) of `sbt`.

With your example it would be something like the following:

```scala
val testJsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testJs", "Run javascript tests.")

testJsTask := {
  // ...whatever logic
}

// then inside your project settings
Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup(() => testJsTask.value)
```

Please notice the `.value` at the end. Without it would be referencing function without invoking it.