# Add additional directory to clean task in SBT build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a SBT build where the tests create temporary files into a directory called temp. How can I tell SBT to delete this folder when I call the clean task?

Comment: Shouldn't your tests clean up after themselves?

Comment: In fact, in normal case the test would clean up the temp files. But in this case I need the temp files to have a look into when sth fails. I simply want to add the temp directory to the directories the clean task deletes.

Comment: Which is the same semantics as `clean` @agilesteel - clean everything even if a previous step failed to do so or was stopped before getting to it. Isn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this setting in the project containing the `temp` directory:

```
cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { base => base / "temp" }
```

This adds the "temp" directory to the list of files to recursively delete when `clean` runs.

The `<` means "configure in terms of other tasks/settings", the `+` means append to the current list of files, and `baseDirectory` is the setting providing the base directory of the project.

You can see how `clean` is configured using the `inspect` command, documented in more detail on the [Inspecting Settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings) page.  An edited sbt session shows usage in this case:

```
> inspect clean
Task: Unit
Description:
    Deletes files produced by the build, such as generated sources, compiled classes, and task caches.
Dependencies:
    clean-files
    clean-keep-files

> inspect clean-files
Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File] = List(<project>/lib_managed, <project>/target, <project>/temp)
Description:
    The files to recursively delete during a clean.
Dependencies:
    managed-directory
    target
    base-directory
```

You can see this shows you if it is a task or setting, the type, a description, and the tasks/settings used as inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Again I learned something more about SBT. Works like a charm now.

Comment: How can we add multiple directories at once? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

[Mark Harrah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10490584/5236247) is now outdated.

Here is a version that works for sbt 0.13 and upwards, and is the only of the two versions that works in sbt 1.0 and onwards.

#### Updated [key appending](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Appending-Values.html) syntax.

Before sbt 0.13, you had the `<+=` syntax for adding additional values, and you could `apply` on keys.

With 0.13, a new, more uniform syntax was introduced, in part called `value` DSL. As of 1.0, the old syntax has been removed.

```
// From the old, apply-based version...
cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { base => base / "temp" }

// ...we change to .value and collection-like syntax
cleanFiles += baseDirectory.value / "temp"
```

`cleanFiles` and other collection-based keys now mimic a (mutable) collection, so you can append values to it via a `+=` operator. If you have multiple values, use `++=` with a `List` or `Seq` instead.

`.value` does not force the evaluation of `baseDirectory` when you write it, but each time `cleanFiles` is calculated, so it's different for each sub-project.

#### Updated inspect and command syntax

There is also a slight difference in the `inspect clean-files` syntax.

1. `hyphen-named-commands` have been deprecated in 0.13 and removed in 1.0. They were replaced with `lowerCamelCaseCommands`, so it's the same in the console as in your `build.sbt`.
2. `inspect` doesn't show the value of your key anymore (I could not find a version information for that). Instead, you have to use `show`.

   ```
   sbt:root-_t> show cleanFiles
   [info] * C:\Users\Adowrath\_T\target\scala-2.12
   [info] * C:\Users\Adowrath\_T\target\streams
   [info] * C:\Users\Adowrath\_T\temp
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed 06.02.2018, 10:28:00
   ```

Comment: This removes contents of the "temp" folder for me, but the folder remains. Is there a way to completely delete it on "clean"?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your tests clean up after themselves, like agilesteel noted.

Another possiblity is that you create a custom cleanup task which depends on the test task.
See my answer here for more information on how to customize existing tasks (like test in your case): [add dependency to existing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554992/how-to-add-dependency-to-existing-rule-in-sbt/8558010#8558010).

Answer (score 1):

The previously suggested solution is deprecated now. Bellow is the code which works for me.

```
cleanFiles += new java.io.File(path)
```