# Where place compiled Javascript class files for SBT and Play Framework 2.1 to find them?

Tags: playframework, sbt, rhino, playframework-2.1

Where should I place my compiled (via Rhino) Javascript classes, for them to be
included on the classpath during compilation, and included in the generated
`dist` bundle?

Play Framework 2.1-RC1 + SBT ignores them, sometimes during
compilation, and sometimes when generating the dist bundles.

#### 1. Placing generated files in `classes/` or `classes_managed/`

If I place the generated .class files here or here:
`target/scala-2.10/classes/`
`target/scala-2.10/classes_managed/`

Then `compile` and `run` works fine. But some weird compilation step (what?!) during `stage` and `dist` fails: it won't find the compiled classes.

#### 2. Placing classes in dedicated directory

If I place the generated .class files here:
`target/scala-2.10/compiledjs-classes/`

And add a classpath entry to SBT's config:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  ...
  def mainSettings = List(
    ...,
    unmanagedClasspath in Compile <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd =>
      Attributed.blank(bd / "target/scala-2.10/compiledjs-classes")
    },
    ...)
```

Then `compile`, `run`, `stage` and `dist` works fine. However! When I unzip and
start the generated .zip file (generated via `dist`), then the application
fails at runtime, because the compiled Javascript classes aren't included in
the .zip.

#### 3. Placing classes in lib/ folder

Then `compile` won't find the class files.
(I placed e.g. class `compiledjs.HtmlSanitizerJs` in
`lib/compiledjs/HtmlSanitizerJs.class`.)

---

What am I supposed to do? I mean, what works and is best practices?

Anyhow, right now I'm copying the generated classes to both
`target/scala-2.10/compiledjs-classes/` (so compilation works) and
`target/scala-2.10/classes/` (so they're included in the generated .zip)
This works, but feels very wrong.

(( Oddly enough, everything worked okay with an older version of Play Framework
(older than RC-1) *and* when I was using PlayProject rather than play.Project.
I then kept the generated classes in `target/scala-2.10/classes/`, only.  ))

Comment: Can you try 2. with a folder that is not in target but in the baseDirectory?

Comment: @Schleichardt Done. Compilation works, but `stage` and `dist` don't work (because `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, when the generated classes aren't found).

Comment: And, in SBT, the `classpath` command doesn't list *the-folder-that-is-not-in-target-but-in-the-baseDirectory*, namely `compiledjs-classes` in my case. However, `show full-classpath` *does* list that folder, `compiledjs-classes`. So what I've done seems to be to tell SBT to include the folder when compiling only, but not when generating a dist?

Comment: In SBT, `clean` won't delete the `compiledjs-classes` folder.

Comment: for the clean problem, there exists a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471596/add-additional-directory-to-clean-task-in-sbt-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to put classfiles to the jars on the stage task. As a workaround I generate a JAR file on stage and on play run I set the classpath to the "rhino" folder in the base folder.

I created a gist for you, so you can check it out and try: https://gist.github.com/4321216 rhino/so/Example.class represents a Rhino class but is only a Java class that returns a String.

Add in your Build.scala:

```
  val rhinoJarName = "rhino.jar"
  val folderForRhinoJar = unmanagedBase
  val rhinoClasspath = (baseDirectory) map { base => Attributed.blank(base / "rhino")}
  val rhinoClassesToJar = TaskKey[Unit]("rhino-classes-to-jar")
  val rhinoClassesToJarInitializer = (base: File, folderForJar: File) => {
    val rhinoFolder = new File(base, "rhino")
    val isClassFile = (file: File) => file.getName.endsWith("class")
    val classFiles =  rhinoFolder.***.filter(isClassFile).get
    val sources = classFiles map { file =>
      file -> file.getCanonicalPath.drop(rhinoFolder.getCanonicalPath.length + 1)
    }
    IO.jar(sources, folderForJar / rhinoJarName, new java.util.jar.Manifest())
  }

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    unmanagedClasspath in Compile <+= rhinoClasspath,
    unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= rhinoClasspath,
    rhinoClassesToJar <<= (baseDirectory, folderForRhinoJar) map rhinoClassesToJarInitializer,
    playStage <<= playStage.dependsOn(rhinoClassesToJar),
    playStage <<= (playStage, folderForRhinoJar) map {(unused, folder) =>
      IO.delete(folder / rhinoJarName)
    },
    cleanFiles <+= folderForRhinoJar { _ / rhinoJarName } //make sure jar will be deleted if play stage does not finish and cleanup jar
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed example :-) I'm not sure if it's "better" to
place the classes in a JAR and include the JAR in the build, rather
than copying the classes directly to the target/scala-2.10/classes/
folder? I think that in my case the latter approach is actually a
little bit simpler, since I'm calling a Makefile script, and I kind of just added a `cp …` line.

Comment: One thing I don't understand, with the example, is: How does Play know
to include the generated JAR, when running stage/dist?  `rhinoClassesToJar` creates the JAR, since
`playStage.dependsOn(rhinoClassesToJar)` — but then what? The JAR gets
created but don't one have to tell SBT to include it in the generated
file bundles somehow?

Comment: SBT is sometimes hardly readable. What really happens: 
I overrite `play dist`. First a JAR with the rhino classes is created into the lib folder (unmanagedBase), then runs the real dist command and sees the rhino.jar and includes it, after that it delete the JAR.