# Scala sbt - Cleaning files with a wildcard or regex

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I have a Scala program that creates files ending in `.foo`.

I'm building with `sbt` and want to remove these files whenever `sbt clean` is called.

[Add additional directory to clean task in SBT build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471596/) shows that a singe file can be added by

```
cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { _ / "test.foo" }
```

However, it's unclear how to extend this to do:

```
cleanFiles <append> <*.foo>
```

All `.foo` files will be in the same directory, so I don't need to recursively check directories.
Though, that would also be interesting to see.

1. How can I configure `sbt` to clean files matching a wildcard, or regex?
2. Is it a bad design decision to have `sbt clean` remove files my program generates?
   Should I instead use a flag in my program? Using `sbt clean` seems cleaner to me rather
   than having to call `sbt clean` then `sbt "run --clean"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will find anything that matches `*.foo` in the base directory (but not child directories):

```
cleanFiles <++= baseDirectory (_ * "*.foo" get)
```

This works because `Seq[File]` gets implicitly converted to a [`PathFinder`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/api/sbt/PathFinder.html), which has methods such as `*` (match the pattern in the base directory) and `**` (match the pattern including child directories). Then `get` converts it back to a `Seq[File]`.

Comment: Note for fellow travelers, the only wildcard supported by sbt currently is "*" and not "[0-9]", for example.  See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths#file-filters