# How do you delete a directory before running in ScalaTest/sbt/Intellij?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I am currently using ScalaTest 3.0.1 for my Scala 2.11.8 project, with sbt 0.13.18 as the build tool. The IDE is Intellij.

The project is a Spark project, and I'm using a temp directory at `root/temp/` for checkpoints and warehousing. When I run the tests multiple times the checkpoints keep getting added to, eventually reaching a very large size. I want to keep the checkpoints around after the test runs so they can be used for verification, but I would like to delete them before the next run.

How can you accomplish this using sbt and ScalaTest in Intellij?

I've been looking into setting up an `sbt clean` with my temp directory in `build.sbt` but I can't seem to get it to delete the directory, and reading the documentary hints it will only delete the files sbt has created, so I abandoned that idea.

I'm currently looking into setting up my ScalaTest set up to have a BeforeAll event which will delete the directory, but I'm not sure this is the correct approach and I've been having issues getting it to work.

Comment: "The IDE is Intellij." What about it?

Comment: Including that in case it's relevant, because I've noticed that Intellij sometimes treats sbt weirdly. I also just realized that I've left the versions off, so I'll go add those in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48659771/5205022 `clean` can include `temp` directory

```
cleanFiles += baseDirectory.value / "temp"
```

Another option is to create a custom task that cleans `temp`, for example using [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files)

```
lazy val deleteTestTemp = taskKey[Unit]("Delete test temp directory")
deleteTestTemp := {
  import better.files._
  val temp = (baseDirectory.value / "temp").toScala
  if (temp.exists) temp.delete()
}
```

where `project/plugins.sbt` contains

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "3.9.1"
```

we could clean and then test like so

```
deleteTestTemp;test
```

Comment: The first approach is the exact same code as I had before but is not working. When I `inspect clean-files` I do see the directory listed, but I don't see any details when I use the `last` command. It simply runs quickly and doesn't delete any files. I am trying to get the second approach working but can't seem to import better.files._ even though I have the module.

Comment: @WarSame Regarding the first approach, if you execute `show cleanFiles` does it list the `temp` directory? Regarding the second approach, make sure to add the dependency under `project/plugins.sbt` or `project/build.sbt` as opposed to `builld.sbt` of the root project, because it need to be a dependency of the meta-project as opposed to project proper as per https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive

Comment: If I execute `show clean-files` or `show cleanFiles` I do see the `temp` directory listed in both though it still isn't getting deleted. 
If I put the `libraryDependency` you mentioned in my `project/plugins.sbt` Intellij gives a hint that `Expression type Def.Setting[Seq[ModuleID]] must conform to DslEntry in sbt file` and cannot resolve the dependency. I tried `addSbtPlugin` which had the same issue. I can't seem to get it to actually find this dependency.