# Execute an sbt command from sbt task or command

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to generate some additional stuff into ./idea/workspace.xml after executing gen-idea command from sbt-idea plugin. I either need to modify gen-idea command to append my code after it's executed or create a new command that runs gen-idea command.
The question would be how to do that?

More generally, how to execute a command from sbt task or command?

Comment: What about [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344477/adding-new-task-dependencies-to-built-in-sbt-tasks)?

Comment: You can't depend on commands this way in sbt. Only on tasks.

Comment: see this discussion on the sbt list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/BY3o3lWWnbU/discussion

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/BY3o3lWWnbU/discussion) it's not possible with sbt up to 0.12.x.

One possible workaround would be defining an alias:

```
alias genidea=; gen-idea; my-gen-stuff
```

in [.sbtrc](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Best-Practices) file